# How to suppress logging of sensitive data in AWS Cloudwatch API logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We have Cloudwatch logging switched on for our API's in the API Gateway service. So all API traffic will be logged to logs with a fixed name like *API-Gateway-Executions-Logs_*. To configure the logging in the AWS Management Console you configure the appropriate stage like shown in the picture below.
[Logs/Tracing tab of the stage editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h41tO.png)

We would like to have the full request/response been logged and switched on the according flag. Now the problem is that the request/response contains sensitive information, which need to be masked, e.g values of headers like Authentication should not be tracked in the log files. For the lambda Cloudwatch logs we have full control what will be logged, e.g. we cleanup the event/context objects before logging them. 
But for API logs I couldn't find a way to assign a custom logger or to define a custom format. Any help to point me into the right direction is highly appreciated.
Thanks,
uwbe

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to restrict what API Gateway will log. You should be restricting user access to those logs if they contain sensitive data.

Comment: I was afraid that this is the answer. Thanks for your response anyway...